# Why aren't my fortran functions exported when using the BIND(C, NAME="name") attribute

Tags: interop, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, intel-fortran

I am used to using the following syntax

```
    subroutine CalcA(A,N)
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: CALCA
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'CalcA' :: CalcA
    IMPLICIT NONE        
    ...
    end subroutine CalcA
```

which produces an exported function in a .dll
[image: DependencyWalker]

So now I am trying the new [`ISO_C_BINDING`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/index.htm#GUID-C0FA4080-4548-4045-9E6D-EFE57A0DE1A3.htm) with the following code

```
    subroutine CalcA(A,N) BIND(C, NAME="CalcA")
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE        
    ...        
    end subroutine CalcA
```

But the export function is not created

[image: DependencyWalker]

**So what am I missing here?** How is the new `iso_c_binding` going to replace the deprecated `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTE DLLEXPORT` declarations?

PS. I am on Intel Fortran XE 2013 on a Win7-64 platform through VS2010.

Comment: I would ask on the Intel Support Forum.

Comment: Someone must know something here .. I hope.

Comment: ISO_C_BINDING just doesn't do what you hope it does.  It adds several predefined constants and procedures that help you interop with C code.  It does *not* automatically export functions, you must still use the DLLEXPORT attribute.

Comment: I see. Put this in an answer and I will award it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't say noone will know I just said I would ask on the vendor's official support forum, nothing more. Why to pay for support otherwise?

Comment: What utility is this that analyses DLLs?

Comment: I am using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) from the VS tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Hans suggests, the procedure wasn't exported because the linker wasn't asked to export it.

The binding label in the BIND clause (the ISO_C_BINDING module is not relevant to the discussion) practically sets the "linker name" of the procedure (similar to what ATTRIBUTES ALIAS does) and does so in a manner that is consistent with C.  The BIND clause also sets the calling convention to be C compatible (similar to ATTRIBUTES C).  The collective effect of the BIND clause also includes that of ATTRIBUTES DECORATE (and there may be other subtle differences between the collective compiler directive attributes and the clause that I've no considered).

There are at least three ways of marking a procedure such that it is exported in a DLL:

- entries in the object file that holds the procedure (this is how ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT works with ifort).
- entries in the EXPORTS section of a module definition file (.DEF) that is passed to the linker at link time.
- command link arguments to the linker itself (/EXPORT:xxx).

What's best for you depends... some prefer to have in-source documentation of the export, others find the visual appearance and non-standard nature of compiler directives intolerably odious.

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out explanation.